# insert key-pair value into nested dict without overwriting after delimiter of key which produce duplicate key

Tags: python, dictionary, split, overwrite

Assume that I have a nested dict like:

```
D={'Germany': {'1972-05-23': 'test1', '1969-12-27': 'test2'},
   'Morocco|Germany': {'1978-01-14':'test3'}}
```

I want to get a new dict like:

```
{'Germany': {'1972-05-23': 'test1', '1969-12-27': 'test2', '1978-01-14':'test3'}
 'Morocco': {'1978-01-14':'test3'}}
```

which means I have to handle the perhaps duplicate key after the `str.split(key)` ,and this is my code:

```
D={'Germany': {'1972-05-23': 'test1', '1969-12-27': 'test2'},
   'Morocco|Germany': {'1978-01-14':'test3'}}

new_dict={}
for item in D:
    for index in str.split(item,'|'):
        new_dict[index]=D[item]
print new_dict
```

however the key-value pair generated after splitting operation overwriting the original ones which result:

```
{'Morocco': {'1978-01-14': 'test3'}, 'Germany': {'1978-01-14': 'test3'}}
```

I wonder how I can modify the my code to get a satisfying dict for further processing or any better solution for this requirement?

PS: My Python Version is 2.7.12 with Anaconda 4.0.0 via IDE PyCharm

Any help will be appreciated, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use:

```
if not index in new_dict: new_dict[index] = {}
new_dict[index].update(D[item])
```